# PowerBI Waterfall Chart - Change Text of Increase/Decrease

Tags: powerbi, waterfall

Can you change the headings of increase/decrease in the Waterfall chart in PowerBI?

[image]

Comment: hi yes, data labels can me updated https://www.tutorialgateway.org/format-power-bi-waterfall-chart/